# CPU Z shows 8 GB ram but task manager shows only 4 GB

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu-z

I just installed a new 4 GB ram stick in my laptop which has only 2 ram slots(1 ram slot is preoccupied with the manufacturer's ram stick).
So the problem is that when I run CPU Z, [CPU Z shows 8 GB ram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZMio.jpg). But Task manager shows [4 GB ram only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCYpu.jpg). How can I fix it? Please help me!!

Comment: Why is it a problem

Comment: Open up the machine. Make sure both modules are seated correctly and making good contact. I've seen machines in the past where SPD (the memory identifier chip) was visible but due to not being fitted correctly the memory itself was not available. If you have four slots you also might want to check your motherboard manual to check which slots should be populated and in which order, it can be important.

Comment: Hi Mokubai! I have tried removing and inserting the memory stick many times but it doesn't help. Even in my BIOS it shows 4096 MB ram. BTW I have only two slots and my motherboard supports maximum 16 GB ram(2 8 GB ram sticks) DDR3. Also if I try to boot just with the new ram stick inserted, my system doesn't boot. Thanks for any further help!!

Comment: The general recommendation is to use two identical or at least similar modules. But yours are very different: One requires a voltage of 1.35V (single rank) the other requires 1.50V (and it is a dual rank module!). Theoretically it should be possible to use the 1.35V module with 1.5V but this does not seem to work on your board. Test if each module alone if it works at all in your board. May be one of the modules is just incompatible to your board?

Comment: Hi @Robert ! When I try to run with the ram stick which requires 1.5V alone, my laptop doesn't boot but it boots if I use the ram stick which requires 1.35V.

Comment: Then you have your answer. The 1.50V dual rank stick is not compatible with your board. It is visible to the system but it can't be used.

Comment: Thanks @Robert ! I just found out that the ram i have is PC3 and my laptop can only support PC3L